# 'form 2.personal details' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, class

My `Employee` class is:

```
class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

`Form1.Cs`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Employee personalDetail = new Employee();

    private void btnSetValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        personalDetail.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(txtEmployeeID.Text);
        personalDetail.Name = txtName.Text;
        personalDetail.Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);

        MessageBox.Show("All data received");
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        personalDetail.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(txtEmployeeID.Text);
        personalDetail.Name = txtName.Text;
        personalDetail.Age= Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);

        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.personalDetail = personalDetail;

        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

`Form2.cs`:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Employee personalDetail = new Employee();
  
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = personalDetail.EmployeeID.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = personalDetail.Name;
        textBox3.Text = personalDetail.Age.ToString();
    }
}
```

In my program I have an `Employee` class and two forms. I am trying to pass arguments from `Form1` to `Form2`, but I get an error. My class and its values are all public.

Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: By default, a member in the class without specifying any access modifier is `private`. That is why you get the mentioned error when trying to access the `personalDetail` field in the `Form2` class. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers#class-record-and-struct-accessibility)

Comment: ```public Employee personalDetail=new Employee();```

Comment: Thank for your response. Now what i did change all to public. Now its working fine.